# Pointer type behavior in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there pointer type assignment in pytorch? What I would like to do is have the following (pseudo-code):

```
b=8
a->b
print(a) --> 8
b=10
print(a) --> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you modify `b` :

```py
# Assign a new object to b : b*2
>>> b = torch.tensor([8]); a=b; print(a); b=b*2; print(a)
tensor([8])
tensor([8])

# Assign a new object to b : tensor([10])
>>> b = torch.tensor([8]); a=b; print(a); b=torch.tensor([10]); print(a)
tensor([8])
tensor([8])

# In-place operation which doesn't assign a new object
>>> b = torch.tensor([8]); a=b; print(a); b*=2; print(a)
tensor([8])
tensor([16])

# In-place operation because it acts directly on the underlying data
>>> b = torch.tensor([8]); a=b; print(a); b.data*=2; print(a)
tensor([8])
tensor([16])
```

So you can't really do pointer assignment in Pytorch...
But you can get the desired result using in-place operations or directly acting on the underlying data of the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the following behavior?

```
b = torch.empty(1)
a = b
print(a.data_ptr() == b.data_ptr()) # ==> True: share the same storage
print(id(a) == id(b))               # ==> True: same python object

b[0] = 8
print(a)   # ==> tensor([8])
b[0] = 10
print(a)   # ==> tensor([10])

print(id(a) == id(b))               # ==> True: still objects are same
```

Comment: basically what I trying to do is make different matrices out of a layers weights by placing each weight at a different entry in these matrices in a specified way. What I would like is that when I step the weights I want all these matrices to get updated automatically.